# The use of base in inheritance context

Tags: c#, inheritance

Could someone please explain to me why the result here is: DVD Unknown  DVD:DVD

```
using System;

class Program
{
    class M
    {
        internal string n;

        internal M() { }
        internal M(string N)
        {
            Console.Write(N + " ");
            n = N;
        }
    }

    class D : M
    {
        internal D(string N) : base(N) { n = "DVD:" + N; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        M d1 = new D("DVD");

        M m1 = new M("Unknown");

        Console.WriteLine(" " + d1.n);

    }
}
```

I understand most parts of the code, except for this line:

```
internal D(string N) : base(N) { n = "DVD:" + N; }
```

I know that base calls something from the parent class, but in this case i just don't get it. :/

Comment: It calls the constructor from the base class. See [base (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)

Comment: ..and then prepends the internal value n with "DVD:"

Comment: `base(n)` calls the constructor of the base class **which has an argument compatible with parameter** *n*. Imagine you would not use `base(n)` - then the compiler will look and call the existing **parameter-less** constructor in your base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break apart this line:

```
internal D(string N) : base(N)
{
    n = "DVD:" + N;
}
```

The part you're most likely needing clarification on is `base(N)`. [`base(N)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) is a call to the `M(string N)` constructor. This happens *before* the body of this constructor (`n = "DVD...`) is run.

I think the code will be clearer if you modify what is printed slightly:

```
class M
{
    internal string n;

    internal M() { }
    internal M(string N)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in base " + N);
        n = N;
    }
}

class D : M
{
    internal D(string N) : base(N) { n = "DVD:" + N; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    M d1 = new D("DVD");

    M m1 = new M("Unknown");

    Console.WriteLine("d1.n is " + d1.n);
}
```

Outputs

```
in base DVD
in base Unknown
d1.n is DVD:DVD
```

The same thing is happening in your output of `DVD Unknown  DVD:DVD`, just all on one line: first, `D`'s constructor calls `M`'s constructor, which writes `DVD` (this happens before `DVD:` is added to it). Then, `M`'s constructor is called directly, which writes `Unknown`. Then, you write `d1`'s `n`, which is `DVD:DVD`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Console.WriteLine(" " + d1.n); will give you DVD:DVD because base means use the parent class' constructor. So, when you send your parameters into your D class, it is sending your code to your M class, it is executing it which gives you "DVD" on your screen and then it is changing the value of n. After that you are sending the "Unknown" value your M class directly which is not related with your D class anymore and it is showing you "Unknown" on your screen. At the end you are requesting D class' n value which is already "DVD". So the result is DVD Unknown DVD:DVD. I hope this makes sense for you.